# Связь многие ко многим Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть 2 таблицы с отношение многие ко многим (deck_users и card_users) + 3 таблица, хранящая эти отношения(deck_users_card_users). В 1 колоде может быть несколько карт, а 1 карта может быть в нескольких колодах. Простой маппинг в классах.

DeckUsersEntity.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<UserCardsEntity> getCardsInDeck() {
    return this.cardsInDeck;
}
```

UserCardsEntity.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cardsInDeck")
public List<DeckUsersEntity> getDecks() {
    return this.decks;
}
```

Упрощенно, таблицы выглядят так. Достаются колоды по id пользователя, по id колоды должны доставаться все карты, относящиеся к ней. Остальные данные тащутся уже со связями один ко многим и с ними проблема нет.

Таблица deck_users

```
id          userid
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
```

Таблица deck_users_card_users

```
deckid        cardsindeck_id
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             1
2             2
2             3
```

Таблица card_users

```
id          cardid
1           8
2           1
3           4
```

Читал туториалы, документацию, но не могу понять в чем проблема. При запросе `session.get(DeckUsersEntity.class, id);` c id=1, которому в deck_users_card_users соответствует 3 записи, возвращается 12 записей. 
Т.е. кол-во колод пользователя (4 шт.) * на кол-во карта в нужной колоде(3). Если карт 4, то возвращается 16 (4*4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось довольно элементарно и очевидно. Необходимо использовать `java.util.Set` вместо `java.util.List`.